# Fackbook SDK throws Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have downloaded and imported android facebook sdk 3.14. It is throwing over 150 errors.

e.g.

```
AppLink cannot be resolved to a type
AppLinkResolver cannot be resolved to a type
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type
```

etc.

I have not even begun implementing the code yet. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: This typically means you didn't import the libraries that the SDK depends on, which include Bolts (bolts.jar) and the Android support library v4, both of which are shipped with the zip file.

Comment: Ming li : Can your please explain how can i import/add Bolt.jar file in project , because i am unable to add this jar in my project .

Comment: @TusharPandey on facebood sdk right click properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jar. Browse to "facebook-android-sdk-master\libs" you will find Android Support V4.jar and bolts.jar. Select those. Go to Order and Export. make sure both the jars are checked.

Comment: @TusharPandey Another advise while importing facebook sdk project please check "copy to workspace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps worked for me:

- Download the facebook sdk from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/
- In Eclipse:

  - Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace
  - Go to the sdk folder location
  - Deselect All and select only 'FacebooSDK' (this if you don't need any samples)
- After the project was imported, clean the project and try to build

It should work now, but if you encounter any further problems, maybe you'll find some help here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 4):

I just found the solution!
As you can notice, there is no `libs` folder in your SDK project.
Create that folder and paste in it `android-support-v4.jar` and `bolts-android-1.1.2.jar` that exisit in this [link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/libs).
Good luck