# Applink cannot be resolved in facebook SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-facebook, applinks

I am working with android.I had integrated facebook sdk into my app.Now facebbok sdk shows the error "Applink cannot be resolved".How can I solve this problem.Please help me I am new to android

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856540/fackbook-sdk-throws-error)

Comment: This question gives a suggested solution -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856540/fackbook-sdk-throws-error

Answer (score 0):

Facebook are update his api then tru this...

```
  LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook);
  loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
   mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
   loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
            Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
        }
    };
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    Log.v("facebook - onCancel", "cancelled");
}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException e) {
    Log.v("facebook - onError", e.getMessage());
}
});
```

And in the onActivityResult(), you have already done like following,

```
 if (mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
   return;
```