# Errors while importing Facebook Android SDK 4.0.1

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add a facebook login to my app. I downloaded the latest facebook sdk (4.0.1) and add the "facebook" project in Eclipse. Then I got  323 errors, most of them were resolved when I added the `android-support-v4.jar` manually.

Now I left with 42 errors, for example "AppLink cannot be resolved to a type".

[image]

How can I solve the errors?

Comment: Did you miss bolts.jar?? If not, then try this: Download the facebook sdk from here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/In Eclipse:Import -> Existing Projects into WorkspaceGo to the sdk folder locationDeselect All and select only 'FacebooSDK' (this if you don't need any samples)After the project was imported, clean the project and try to build.

Comment: Did you miss bolts.jar?? Have a look at https://icl.googleusercontent.com/?lite_url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856540/fackbook-sdk-throws-error&ei=DLSyIiuA&lc=en-IN&s=1

Comment: A much easier way is to use Gradle and just add the 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:x.x.x' dependency. This is all documented in the https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android. Highly recommend you take a look if you're having issues with set up.

Answer (score 0):

download bolt.jar from [this](https://codeload.github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/zip/master) link and import it as library

```
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/archive/master.zip
```